# Is there a relationship formula between Bond YTM, ZSpread ( to OIS ) and OIS rate?

Tags: fixed-income, bond, bond-yields

It seems to me that :
$$\begin{aligned}
P_{Dirty} &= \sum_i(\text{cashflow}_i * \exp( - \text{yield} * t_i ) ) \\
                            &= \sum_i( \text{cashflow}_i * \exp( - ( \text{OIS}_i + \text{Zsprd} ) * t_i )
\end{aligned}
$$
Than should we have some approximation like : $\text{Yld} = \text{OIS}_{t=duration} + \text{Zsprd}$  ?

Comment: Sure, but this is true under your own definition of Z-spread. You have defined the continuously compounded Z-spd to be the amount that you add to the continuously compounded OIS rate to arrive at the continuosly compounded yield to maturity. This says nothing more than that.